# my satellite circumnavigates, but along a non-circular path (correcting spherical coord math)

Tags: c++, macos, math, opengl

This is how I position my torus (satellite) upon a sphere, and then rotate it around the sphere:

```
    int satellite_1_1_step = 0;
    int &r_satellite_1_1_step = satellite_1_1_step;
    float satellite_1_1_divider = 300;

    float satellite_1_1_theta = 6.5;
    float satellite_1_1_phi = 1;
    float satellite_1_1_theta_increment = 20/satellite_1_1_divider;
    float satellite_1_1_phi_increment = 20/satellite_1_1_divider;

    void satellite_1_1 ()
    {
            float satellite_1_1_theta_math = (satellite_1_1_theta-(satellite_1_1_theta_increment * r_satellite_1_1_step))/10.0*M_PI;
            float satellite_1_1_phi_math = (satellite_1_1_phi-(satellite_1_1_phi_increment * r_satellite_1_1_step))/10.0*2*M_PI;
            r_satellite_1_1_x = radius_exodus_pos * sin(satellite_1_1_theta_math) * cos(satellite_1_1_phi_math);
            r_satellite_1_1_y = radius_exodus_pos * sin(satellite_1_1_theta_math) * sin(satellite_1_1_phi_math);
            r_satellite_1_1_z = radius_exodus_pos * cos(satellite_1_1_theta_math);  

            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(r_satellite_1_1_x,r_satellite_1_1_y,r_satellite_1_1_z);
            glColor3f(1,0,0);
            glutSolidTorus(0.04, 0.2, 10, 100);
            glEnd();
            glPopMatrix();
    }
```

This is how I update and increment its position:

```
    void satellite_1_1_increment()
    {

    if (r_satellite_1_1_step < satellite_1_1_divider)   
        {
        ++(r_satellite_1_1_step); 
        }

    if (r_satellite_1_1_step >= satellite_1_1_divider)  
        {
        r_satellite_1_1_step = 1;  
        }
    }
```

So, my torus (satellite) moves around the sphere, ending back up in its starting position, and continues over again - which is great. However, the path it takes wobbles around the poles (I think) along the way - rather than simply circumnavigating the sphere.

Is there an improvement that can be made to my math which will cause the satellite to circumnavigate the sphere in a more circular path?

Answer (score 1):

The first issue I see is this:

```
void satellite_1_1_increment()
{
    if (r_satellite_1_1_step < satellite_1_1_divider)   
    {
        ++(r_satellite_1_1_step); 
    }

    if (r_satellite_1_1_step >= satellite_1_1_divider)  
    {
        r_satellite_1_1_step = 1;  
    }
}
```

What happens at the edge case when the step is incremented by the first test such that it satisfies the second test?  It is immediately reset, thus missing the value.  I think you want it written like this to avoid that problem:

```
void satellite_1_1_increment()
{
    if (r_satellite_1_1_step >= satellite_1_1_divider)   
           r_satellite_1_1_step = 1;  
    else   ++r_satellite_1_1_step;
}
```

Is `1` the correct reset value?  Maybe it should be `0`?

Comment: Thankyou for the response wallyk. That certainly makes the increment more fullproof - I appreciate that. However, the satellite still 'snakes' around the sphere at the poles, rather than circumnavigating it in a more circular path.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the first two lines of:

```
    void satellite_1_1 ()
    float satellite_1_1_theta_math = (satellite_1_1_theta+(satellite_1_1_theta_increment* r_satellite_1_1_step))*M_PI;
    float satellite_1_1_phi_math = (satellite_1_1_phi-(satellite_1_1_phi_increment* r_satellite_1_1_step))*M_PI/360;
```

Now the satellite orbits 360 degrees along the equator. Adding a glRotatef after my glPushMatrix lets me fine tune its axis.

Thanks again wallyk. - kropcke